# Replacing specific multiple values in list

Tags: python, list, replace

Before you mark this as duplicate, please read through.

I am trying to find and replace a certain value in a list.
The list looks like this:

```
[score                      405.738
 start    2015-11-10 06:04:00+00:00
 stop     2015-11-10 06:55:00+00:00
 Name: 23, dtype: object, score                      401.088
 start    2015-11-10 05:41:00+00:00
 stop     2015-11-10 06:32:00+00:00
 Name: 0, dtype: object]
```

Let's say this is list_v.
Printing list_v[0] gives:

```
score                      405.738
start    2015-11-10 06:04:00+00:00
stop     2015-11-10 06:55:00+00:00
Name: 23, dtype: object
```

What I want is **something like** this:

```
if current_value['score'] in list_v:
    ind = list_v.index(current_value['score'])
```

Then, I would simply overwrite whatever is inside that index.

I get this error:

> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)

This **would** work if my list looked like this:

```
[405.73842646140832,
 Timestamp('2015-11-10 06:04:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-11-10 06:55:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 401.0883140755235,
 Timestamp('2015-11-10 05:41:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-11-10 06:32:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
```

However, it doesn't, and I don't want it to, because I would like to transform it into a dataframe later on.
Transforming the first into a dataframe gives me what I want:

```
score   start   stop
23  405.738426  2015-11-10 06:04:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:55:00+00:00
0   401.088314  2015-11-10 05:41:00+00:00   2015-11-10 06:32:00+00:00
```

Automatically creating columns and rows with the exact indices and column names needed.
But then I am unable to replace certain values that I am trying to find.

Comment: why exactly can't you replace them from within the data frame?

Comment: that seems like something completely doable in `pandas`

Comment: Yeah it is! I know how to do it in pandas, but I want to try it in a list

Comment: This is because the operations I am doing, apart from this one, seems to be much faster with normal lists than dataframe pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that come to mind are either copy the scores into a separate list or write a function to search for scores in your DataFrame.

If you're data isn't too big, copying the scores is probably a bit cleaner:

```
data = [{
    'name': 'First Thing',
    'score': 1
}, {
    'name': 'Second Thing',
    'score': 2
}]

scores = [d['score'] for d in data]

# Tested with a value that is a valid score and one that isn't.
current_value = {'score': 1}
# current_value = {'score': -1}

if current_value['score'] in scores:
    ind = scores.index(current_value['score'])
    print('Index: %d' % ind)
    print(data[ind])
else:
    print('Score not found.')
```

(I don't have pandas right now so this example uses a list with dicts instead).

Alternatively, you could use a custom search function:

```
def find_score(data):
    for ind, d in enumerate(data):
        if current_value['score'] == d['score']:
            return ind, d
    return None, None

ind, d = find_score(data)
if ind is not None:
    print('Index: %d' % ind)
    print(d)
else:
    print('Score not found')
```